# getting lag when loading and playing sounds

Tags: java, audio, lag

i wrote a little sound class where i can make a sound and toggle it and stuff but im not too great and i had to at least temporarily scrap it. i tried a little method to load sound and play it and then when it ends to unload it. it causes a lot of lag though. the class i had before would do the same thing as far as i can see but it didnt discard the sound properly and the soundswouldnt load anymore. heres my method thats causing ober lag but is working for what it should do. i need help refining it please.

```
    public static void runOnce(final String location) {
            try {
            File audioFile = new File(Game.gameFolder + "/sounds/" + location);
            final AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

            final Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            audioClip.open(audioStream);
            audioClip.start();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (audioClip.isActive()) {}
                    try {
                    audioClip.close();
                    audioStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }).start();

            } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Comment: `while (audioClip.isActive()) {}` isn't going to be health for the CPU as it's going to be constantly running through the empty look, consider adding `Thread.yield` or `Thread.sleep` within the loop...I seem to remember a way to call a blocking method to wait till the stream has completed, `drain` or something...?

Comment: Try using `audioClip.drain()` instead of the `while-loop`...

Comment: I will try the drain later today and see what happens thanks

Comment: it took off the lag for sure but later on it gave the error later on in the program and wouldnt load the sound anymore

Comment: forget what i said about the error. i addidentally un remarked my old sound code for it. let me try it again